# Sanity Studio not taking projectId

Tags: typescript, deployment, sanity

`sanity.config.ts`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'sanity';
import { deskTool } from 'sanity/desk';
import { presentationTool } from 'sanity/presentation';
import { visionTool } from '@sanity/vision';
import { colorInput } from '@sanity/color-input';
import { media } from 'sanity-plugin-media';
import { debugSecrets } from '@sanity/preview-url-secret/sanity-plugin-debug-secrets'

import { locate } from '@/sanity/utils/locate';
import { schemaTypes } from '@/sanity/schemas';

import { defaultDocumentNode, deskStructure } from '@/sanity/deskStructure';
import { getClient } from '@/sanity/client';
import { createQueryStore } from '@sanity/react-loader';


const client = getClient({ token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_READ_TOKEN });


export default defineConfig({
  name: 'default',
  title: 'Test project',

  basePath: '/admin/cms',

  projectId: 'jf3lljf', // <-- not my real id, obvs!
  dataset: 'production',
  useCdn: false,
  apiVersion: '2021-10-21',

  plugins: [
    presentationTool({
      previewUrl: {
        origin: typeof location === 'undefined' ? 'http://localhost:3000' : location.origin,
        draftMode: {
          enable: '/api/draft',
        },
      },
      locate,
    }),
    deskTool({
      structure: deskStructure,
      defaultDocumentNode,
    }),
    visionTool(),
    media(),
    colorInput(),
    debugSecrets(),
  ],

  schema: {
    // @ts-ignore
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
});

export const { loadQuery, useQuery, useLiveMode } = createQueryStore({
  client,
});
```

`sanity.cli.ts`

```js
import { loadEnvConfig } from "@next/env";
import { defineCliConfig } from "sanity/cli";
import { UserConfig } from "vite";
import tsConfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
loadEnvConfig(__dirname, dev, { info: () => null, error: console.error });


export default defineCliConfig({
  api: {
    projectId: 'jf3lljf',
    dataset: 'production'
  },
  vite: (viteConfig: UserConfig): UserConfig => ({
    ...viteConfig,
    plugins: [tsConfigPaths(), ...(viteConfig.plugins || [])],
    // ...rest of config
  }),
});
```

---

When I do `sanity deploy` I get a successful deploy

```
Including the following environment variables as part of the JavaScript bundle:
- SANITY_STUDIO_API_DATASET
- SANITY_STUDIO_API_PROJECT_ID

✔ Clean output folder (11ms)
✔ Build Sanity Studio (24866ms)
✔ Verifying local content
✔ Deploying to Sanity.Studio

Success! Studio deployed to https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/
```

but when I go to the studio URL I get:

```
Uncaught error: Configuration must contain `projectId`
https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:1554:9004
Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`
    at pKe (https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:1554:9004)
    at JG.config (https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:1554:25165)
    at new JG (https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:1554:24630)
    at createClient (https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:1554:26121)
    at FGr (https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:6991:9954)
    at zGr (https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:6991:10325)
    at vYr (https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:6991:14981)
    at https://the-jump-student-portal.sanity.studio/static/sanity-f12a5dea.js:7010:8950
```

**Note that I DON'T use them here but the actual environment variable values mentioned in the build are also present in .env.local:**

```bash
SANITY_STUDIO_API_DATASET=production
SANITY_STUDIO_API_PROJECT_ID=jf3lljf
```

Comment: I just ran into something similar. My package.json did not explicitly define @next/env and I believe it was silently failing. As soon as I installed @next/env the problem was resolved.